# Users cant share the content on the site!

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions

In SharePoint 2013, i can see the share button in ribbon and i can see the form for inviting people. when i fill up the form and click on share, it says , your request has been declined!

We have recently migrated our site from 2010 to 2013

what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

The permissions are broke.  Check the permissions to see if they still have them.  If they do and you still cannot share then delete the user and re-add them.